# How can I use "parallel for" instead of using a few "for"?

Tags: c#, image-processing, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I am trying to write a faster code for sobel but I could not understand to use it for several for loop?

Should I use as many parallel for as the number of loops?

Is this get effective?

Can somebody explain it on codes: Here is the codes:

```
for (int y = 0; y < Image.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < Image.Width * 3; x += 3)
    {
        r_x = g_x = b_x = 0; //reset the gradients in x-direcion values
        r_y = g_y = b_y = 0; //reset the gradients in y-direction values
        location = x + y * ImageData.Stride; //to get the location of any pixel >> location = x + y * Stride
        for (int yy = -(int)Math.Floor(weights_y.GetLength(0) / 2.0d), yyy = 0; yy <= (int)Math.Floor(weights_y.GetLength(0) / 2.0d); yy++, yyy++)
        {
            if (y + yy >= 0 && y + yy < Image.Height) //to prevent crossing the bounds of the array
            {
                for (int xx = -(int)Math.Floor(weights_x.GetLength(1) / 2.0d) * 3, xxx = 0; xx <= (int)Math.Floor(weights_x.GetLength(1) / 2.0d) * 3; xx += 3, xxx++)
                {
                    if (x + xx >= 0 && x + xx <= Image.Width * 3 - 3) //to prevent crossing the bounds of the array
                    {
                        location2 = x + xx + (yy + y) * ImageData.Stride; //to get the location of any pixel >> location = x + y * Stride

                        sbyte weight_x = weights_x[yyy, xxx];
                        sbyte weight_y = weights_y[yyy, xxx];
                        //applying the same weight to all channels
                        b_x += buffer[location2] * weight_x;
                        g_x += buffer[location2 + 1] * weight_x; //G_X
                        r_x += buffer[location2 + 2] * weight_x;
                        b_y += buffer[location2] * weight_y;
                        g_y += buffer[location2 + 1] * weight_y;//G_Y
                        r_y += buffer[location2 + 2] * weight_y;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //getting the magnitude for each channel
        b = (int)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(b_x, 2) + Math.Pow(b_y, 2));
        g = (int)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(g_x, 2) + Math.Pow(g_y, 2));//G
        r = (int)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(r_x, 2) + Math.Pow(r_y, 2));

        if (b > 255) b = 255;
        if (g > 255) g = 255;
        if (r > 255) r = 255;

        //getting grayscale value
        grayscale = (b + g + r) / 3;

        //thresholding to clean up the background
        //if (grayscale < 80) grayscale = 0;
        buffer2[location] = (byte)grayscale;
        buffer2[location + 1] = (byte)grayscale;
        buffer2[location + 2] = (byte)grayscale;
        //thresholding to clean up the background
        //if (b < 100) b = 0;
        //if (g < 100) g = 0;
        //if (r < 100) r = 0;

        //buffer2[location] = (byte)b;
        //buffer2[location + 1] = (byte)g;
        //buffer2[location + 2] = (byte)r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can sobel be done in parallel? my spidey senses say no even without looking at your code

Comment: First get some some numbers : Benchmark.NET. Then pinpoint bottlenecks. Then plan improvements, again measure their effect. Don't wildly assume possible solutions.

Comment: Please try to avoid [over-parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-with-plinq#avoid-over-parallelization). The cardinality might help you to decide which loop could be executed in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.I am gonna research the things that you recommended.@ 
Fildor@ 
Peter Csala

Comment: note: some trivial optimizations that may or may not help: consider hoisting `weights_x.GetLength(1)` and `weights_y.GetLength(0)` before the loop; it would be worth testing (benchmarking) whether `Math.Pow(b_x, 2)` vs `b_x * b_x` is faster (etc); maybe hoist the width, stride, etc

Comment: Replace the outer loop only with `Parallel.For(0, Image.Height, (y)=> { ... });`

Answer (score 4):

The most important questions are: *is* the work trivially parallelizable, and does the object model you're using *support concurrency*. Things that are purely math related and where the outcomes aren't cumulative *tend* to be parallelizable, but I can't comment on the object model's thread-safety. It isn't guaranteed (and the default is usually "no").

As for where:

There is very little point having nested parallelism; parallelism has overheads, and magnifying those overheads is counter-productive. The most effective way to treat parallelism is to think "chunky" - i.e. a relatively small number of non-trivial operations (but hopefully at least as many as available CPU cores), rather than huge numbers of trivial operations. As such, the most effective place to put parallelism is usually: the outermost loop. In this case, this seems to map to rows in an image, which seems a reasonable way to partition image processing. You *could* partition it into Nths (for CPU cores N), but honestly: I suspect rows will work just fine, and keeps things simple.

However! Note that you need to avoid shared state: `r_x`, `g_x` and `b_x` and the same for the `_y` parts (and any other shared locals) would need to be declared **inside** the parallel part, to ensure that they are independent. Other things to look at: `grayscale`, `location`, `location2`, `r`, `g`, `b`, `yyy`, `xxx`. It would be good to see where these things are currently declared, but my suspicion is that they'd all need to be moved so that they're declared *inside* the parallel portion. Check *all* locals that are declared, and all fields that are accessed.

It looks like `buffer` and `buffer2` are simply input/output arrays, in which case: they *should* work OK in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Then I am gonna try to do this method for the outermost for.@Marc Gravell

Comment: @stck_n as I say: watch out for accidentally introducing shared state